# Como hacer que 2 botones se desplacen hacia abajo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas comunidad tengo un problema con mi sistema en movil, lo que pasa es que desde el primer momento mis 2 botones me cubren información, como podría hacer que esos 2 botones recién se muevan cuando me deslizo hacia bajo.
Imagen referencial sin y con css: https://ibb.co/kyFt1f9

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .row2{
        z-index:50;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top:0cm;
        top: 40;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
      <section class="content-header" >
      <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row row2 justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-sm-4" id="aprobado">
            <button type="button" id="btnconfir" class="btnapro btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Aceptar_Venta()">Aprobado</buttton>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" id="rechazado">
            <button type="button"  id="btnrech" class="btrecha btn btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="Rechazar_Venta()">Rechazado</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: cambia el fixed por relative y adapta el css segun necesites

Comment: con relative se queda fijo

Answer (score 0):

Una solución más adecuado sería usar `sticky` en vez de `fixed`. La posición `sticky` actúa relativamente con el scroll, y queda fijo en su contenedor padre cuando se hace scroll.

Como no mostraste completo tu código y no se la estructura completa, dedusco que `row` quieres que se quede fijo.
Bien, usando `sticky` resolvería esto.  Queda fijo, pero solamente cuando se hace scroll. Es un buen diseño en CSS.

Para usar `sticky`, su contenedor padre deve ser `position: relative`, y por lo menos el doble de su altura en `height` (no importa si su contenedor padre cresca, o tenga muchos contenidos). No importa donde este ubicado `row`, siempre cuando `row` llega arriba de la pantalla, se queda alli visible.
Para que éste `row` con posición `sticky` quede pegado arriba, debe tener `top: 0`. El resto es adaptar a tu estilo propio.

Yo opte por darle al mismo `row` la posición `sticky`.
También agregué colores para diferenciar y una altura extra para visualizar.

*Ya tu puedes adaptar y tener la idea a tu estilo*.

**Esto funciona solamente en un teléfono móvil**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
 
 .container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red
 }
 
 .row2{ 
  z-index:50;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: violet
 } 

}
```

```html
<section class="content-header" > 
   
   <div class="content"> 

<div class="container-fluid">
 
 <div class="row row2 justify-content-around"> 
  
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="aprobado"> 
   <button type="button" id="btnconfir" class="btnapro btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" onclick="Aceptar_Venta()">Aprobado</buttton> 
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="rechazado"> 
   <button type="button" id="btnrech" class="btrecha btn btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="Rechazar_Venta()">Rechazado</button> 
  </div> 
 
 </div> 
 
 <h1>Siguiente contenido del container </h1>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

 
</div> 

<h1>section</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Lo que me pasaste esta bien poniendoel fixed pero solo me muestra 1 boton: https://ibb.co/hfZjFfZ

Comment: segun entiendo en tu imagen, es que el `header` esta fijo, entonces todo el contenido que no es fijo, se queda debajo del `header`.

Comment: Se puede poner un `padding-top: xx` al contenedor del header y los demas. Este puede ser el `body`.  Si el header es de `height: 100px`, entonces `body {padding-top: 100px}`

Comment: Hice lo q dice pero me afecta al siderbar y me queda un gran espacio en la parte de arriba imagen del resultado: https://ibb.co/XzSdFcS

Comment: Seria mejor si pudiera agregar todo tu codigo. Auque tu problema es detalle, se nota que te es dificil solucionar. Entonces, para no destruir tu pagina haciendo modificaciones sin entender, podrias agregar todo tu codigo?

Comment: Mi código casi completo esta aquí espero me pueda ayudar: https://jsfiddle.net/luiss1/40cbuwvs/4/